# Mercurial: How to restore after rebase

Tags: mercurial, backup, restore, rebase

I've accidentally pulled some changes from the main repo with --rebase parameter.

How do I restore the original repository state from the backup which was created during the rebase?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`hg unbundle` is used to apply the backup file:

```
hg unbundle .hg/strip-backup/e64394fd5837-backup.hg
```

However, this does not remove the new changesets that have been created by the rebase; it is probably a good idea to call `hg unbundle` from a repo that does not have the rebased changesets (i.e. clone latest version from server).

Comment: Or `strip` the new changesets, but Daniel’s suggestion is better.